# computing radial, along track, cross track components (differences) from two ECEF coordinates and velocities

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbital-elements

I need to compute radial, along track, cross track components (differences) for two points in the orbital planes. I found the unit vectors of radial, along track, cross track but couldn't sure how these can be transformed to distance in km. My computations as follows;

```
r_1=[x_final;y_final;z_final] % first coordinate vector,  km
r_2=[x_ultra;y_ultra;z_ultra] % second coordinate vector, km

v_1=[vx_1;vy_1;vz_1] % velocities of first coordinates,km/sec 
v_2=[vx_2;vy_2;vz_2] % velocities of second coordinates,km/sec
```

% computation of direction of unit vectors

```
ea_1=v_1/norm(v_1)                     % along direction unit vector of first point
ec_1=(r_1 x v_1) / norm(r_1 x v_1)     % cross-track direction unit vector of first point
er_1=ea_1 x ec_1                       % radial direction unit vector of first point

ea_2=v_2/norm(v_2)                     % along direction unit vector of second point
ec_2=(r_2 x v_2) / norm(r_2 x v_2)     % cross-track direction unit vector of second point
er_2=ea_2 x ec_2                       % radial direction unit vector of second point


 % converting direction of unit vectors to distance (km) 

radial_difference= norm((er_1*r_1)-(er_2*r_2)) % between first and second points, unit km
cross_difference=  norm((ec_1*r_1)-(ec_2*r_2)) % between first and second points, unit km
along_difference=  norm((ea_1*r_1)-(ea_2*r_2)) % between first and second points, unit km
```

Does above approach to converting direction unit vector to distance correct?

unit vectors computations are based on https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs10291-014-0369-5.pdf in "RTS products application" section.

Comment: `-1` I think you should take the time to write your question using *math and sentences*, not a block of pseudocode. It would be best if *explained* your computations so that readers don't have to become programmers just to read this Space Exploration SE question. Usually people use MathJax to enter equations. You can read further in this tutorial; https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/284619

Comment: Things like `r_1=[x_final;y_final;z_final] % first coordinate vector,  km` (defining a vector as a group of three components) certainly does not have to be explained here, that's just part of the programming language. Stick to math part, this stuff just makes the question harder to read.

Comment: This isn't really a space exploration question so much as it is a simple coordinate transformation exercise.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. It's just a maths transformation question.